# Can I use the dropdown list in attributes table for several selected features in one time?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, dropdownlist

I use some dropdown lists for several attributes. Now I want to select several features (objects) and edit a field using the dropdown list.

Is there a way to do it in one time, because it looks like you can use the dropdown list only on one single feature and not for all selected features in one time?

[image]

[image]